# Error(20,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INSERT" error

Tags: plsql

> Error(20,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INSERT"

I have been getting an insert symbol error whenever I try to execute my DDL trigger. Can someone help please I have tried to find an answer and nothing seems clear. My code down below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER HR_AUDIT_TR
BEFORE DDL ON SCHEMA
BEGIN

INSERT INTO SHEMA_AUDIT VALUES 
  (SYSDATE , 
   SYS_COTEXT('USERENV' , 'CURRENT_USER') , 
   ORA_DICT_OBJ_TYPE ,
   ORA_DICT_OBJ_NAME , 
   ORA_SYSEVENT );

END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not `SYS_COTEXT` but `SYS_CONTEXT`.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER HR_AUDIT_TR
  2    BEFORE DDL ON SCHEMA
  3  BEGIN
  4  INSERT INTO SHEMA_AUDIT VALUES
  5    (SYSDATE ,
  6     SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV' , 'CURRENT_USER') ,    --> here
  7     ORA_DICT_OBJ_TYPE ,
  8     ORA_DICT_OBJ_NAME ,
  9     ORA_SYSEVENT );
 10  END;
 11  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```